# Убрать вложенность git subtree

Tags: git

После своей предыдущей темы прочитал про submodule и subtree. Создал следущую структуру репозиториев:

1. Application
2. Infrastructure(зависит от 1)
3. Client(зависит от 1 и 2)

В Infrastructure добавляю subtree так:

```
git subtree add --prefix=subtrees/Application url main --squash
```

В Client добавляю subtree так:

```
git subtree add --prefix=subtrees/Application url main --squash
git subtree add --prefix=subtrees/Module url main --squash
```

И внутри subtrees/Module есть своя папка subtree с Application. Мне это не нравится и я думаю это неправильно. Можно ли как-то исключить subtrees из других репозиториев, чтобы не плодить ненужные папки.

Comment: Есть мнение, что сабмодули не нужны.

Comment: @user7860670 сабмодули, да, но subtree? Сейчас тестирую локальный nuget-сервер через папку вообще.